# Runtime error despite code running error-free in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm solving a question on Leetcode and though my code works perfectly well when I run it and also gives the correct answers for multiple test cases, the Leetcode checker does not accept it and gives a runtime error. Could anyone pls tell me why this is happening?

**Problem statement:**
Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.

If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".

**Code:**

```
class Solution:
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
        '''
        logic: Compare each letter of the first word with corresponding letters of all subsequent words.
        '''
        for i in range(len(strs[0])):
            char = strs[0][i]
            for j in range(1, len(strs)):
                if char != strs[j][i]:
                    return strs[0][0:i]    # consider answer as soon as first inequality encountered
```

**Error:**

```
Runtime Error Message:
IndexError: list index out of range
    for i in range(len(strs[0])):
Line 6 in longestCommonPrefix (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().longestCommonPrefix(param_1)
Line 31 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 42 in <module> (Solution.py)
Last executed input:
[]
```

Thanks!

Comment: If the `strs` list is empty then `strs[0]` will error.

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you :)